# How to format XML using WriteStartDocument WriteStartElement WriteAttributeString in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I want the XML in format like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ftc:A xmlns="urn:oecd:ties:stfatypes:v1" xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:a:v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.a.com/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:a:v1 aXML_v1.1.xsd">
    <ftc:b>
        <z issuedBy = "s">1</z>
        <x>CO</x>
    </ftc:b>
</ftc:A>
```

I forget the attribute issuedBy,
I've had trouble writing the attributes whit the methods:

```
writer.WriteStartDocument ();
writer.WriteStartElement ();
writer.WriteAttributeString ();
writer.WriteElementString ();
```

I just need the example in C# please :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the `XDocument` (LINQ to XML) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like t3chb0t said, the newer classes like `XDocument` would make this easier. But assuming you need to use XmlWriter, here's how you can do it:

```
const string rootNamespace = "urn:oecd:ties:stfatypes:v1";
const string ftcNamespace = "urn:oecd:ties:a:v1";
const string xsiNamespace = "http://www.a.com/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
};

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("ftc", "A", ftcNamespace);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "", null, rootNamespace);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "ftc", null, ftcNamespace);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, xsiNamespace);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.1");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("schemaLocation", xsiNamespace, "urn:oecd:ties:a:v1 aXML_v1.1.xsd");
    writer.WriteStartElement("b", ftcNamespace);
    writer.WriteElementString("z", rootNamespace, "1");
    writer.WriteElementString("x", rootNamespace, "CO");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? You should use [`WriteStartElement("ftc","A","ftcNamespace")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cdfkth5.aspx)

Comment: What you have is the proper way of doing it. I thought I had tried that, but saw XmlWriter throw an exception on the next line, where I set the default namespace to rootNamespace. So I made it work with the "ftc:A" hack, which isn't proper but does work. Looking back, I probably accidentally missed passing in the explicit prefix. I'll edit the answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: the response is excellent and works daspek, if you say it is easier with XDocument like I see it,  thank you very much

Comment: the response is excellent and works daspek, if you say it is easier with XDocument, i want to see it, thank you very much

Comment: i forgot <z issuedBy = "s">1</z>

Comment: Replace the WriteElementString for `z` with this:

     `writer.WriteStartElement("z", rootNamespace);`
     `writer.WriteAttributeString("issuedBy", "s");`
     `writer.WriteValue("1");`
     `writer.WriteEndElement();`